# Confluence: Activating Microsoft SSO

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, confluence

I have a group of users that will need to access our documentation in Confluence using their Microsoft login credentials. I'm using this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/confluencemicrosoft-tutorial) to activate Microsoft SSO but I'm stuck on step 3 under [Configure Confluence SAML SSO by Microsoft SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/confluencemicrosoft-tutorial#configure-confluence-saml-sso-by-microsoft-sso).
When I try to upload the file I downloaded, Confluence shows me this but the tutorial doesn't mention a descriptor URL. Does anyone know what I should enter here?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can get some idea from below references:

- The [***app descriptor***](https://developer.atlassian.com.rproxy.goskope.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/app-descriptor/) is a JSON file which actually describes
  the app to the Atlassian application. The `atlassian-connect.json`
  serves the same function. ***`The descriptor serves as the glue between the remote app and the Atlassian application.`***

> When an admin of cloud instance installs an app, they are actually
> installing this descriptor file, which has pointers to your service.

See [***Confluence Connect App - Create App Descriptors  GitLab***](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/225603)

- The descriptor basically includes general information for the app, as
  well as the modules that the app wants to use or extend.
  ***[confluence-global-schema.json.](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/connect-schemas/raw/master/confluence-global-schema.json)***
- Some app changes require a change to the descriptor file
  itself.[confluence modules dialog](https://developer.atlassian.com.rproxy.goskope.com/cloud/confluence/modules/dialog/)